# Transform error:unknown plugin "transform-decorators" specified in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, babel-jest

I am getting this after installing jest, and transform-decorators-legacy.
But jest is running successfully and passing tests for each screen.

I am using MOBX for stores.
[image]

bablerc file :

```
       {
       "presets": ["react-native","babel-preset-expo","react-native-
       stage-0/decorator-support"],
       "env": {
       "development": {
       "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source","transform-decorators  
       -legacy"]
       }
      }
      }
```

package.json

```
                        "scripts": {
                          "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest"
                        },
                        "jest": {
                          "preset": "jest-expo"
                        },
                        "author": null,
                        "private": true,
                        "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
                        "dependencies": {
                          "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
                          "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
                          "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
                          "expo": "^21.0.0",
                          "mobx": "^3.3.1",
                          "mobx-react": "^4.3.3",
                          "native-base": "^2.3.3",
                          "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
                          "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-21.0.2.tar.gz",
                          "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
                          "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
                          "react-native-modal": "^4.1.0",
                          "react-native-prompt": "^1.0.0",
                          "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.15"
                        },
                        "devDependencies": {
                          "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
                          "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
                          "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
                          "cavy": "^0.4.1",
                          "jest": "^21.2.1",
                          "jest-expo": "^22.0.1-SNAPSHOT.2017.11.1",
                          "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
                          "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
                          "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0"
                        }
                      }
```